# Trying to Dequeue but it only prints the last value i queued

Tags: java, queue, project

For my java project, whenever I Queue something, for example 1,2,3,5,6,7,8;

When I dequeue something for example in my while loop, it would keep printing 8,8,8,8,8,8,8

Why? What would be the best way to fix this?

Thank you so much!

```
public static Object buildObject(ArrayList<Integer> points) {   
    Queue<Object> QueuePoints = new Queue<Object>();
    Object T = new Object(0,0,0);
    int A = points.size();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<A;i++){
        T.splitValue= points.get(i);
        T.maxSplitValue = points.get(i);
        T.minSplitValue = points.get(i);
        QueuePoints.enqueue(T);

    }
    while(!QueuePoints.isempty){
        System.out.print(QueuePoints.dequeue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Queue is an interface and you cannot instantiate an interface directly, you need to instantiate a class that implements the interface Queue such as LinkedList etc...

To initialize the Queue and get rid of the errors you need something like this:

```
Queue<Integer> myQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```